# Trying to test Python on Win 10, getting Errno 2. Path to python is given to the value of env variable

Tags: python-3.x, windows, environment-variables

I've installed Python 3.8 on Win 10 machine. Path to Python is `C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\`

Path environment variable values are: `C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe`

In order to test python, I created a simple script called "script.py" in directory `C:\python_scripts`.
Then I tried to run "script.py" from the directory where it is located, but got error:

```
C:\python_scripts> python script.py
C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe: can't open file 'script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What might be the cause of getting this error? i tried to run the script with both cmd and powershell, with the usual user rights and with elevated admin rights, still getting Errno 2.

No other versions of Python have been previously installed on this machine (which is a corporate one, if that might be significant)

Thank you

Comment: Can you show the result of `dir` in that directory? It seems like that file simply isn't there or you have a typo

Comment: `PATH` should only contain directories, not files, i.e. it should have "C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38", not "C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe".

Comment: Thank you @OferSadan for your suggestion, it helped me to solve the problem. The "script.py" had an additional .txt extension added to it, but the Windows explorer only showed .py extension by default. Now I deleted the trailing .txt suffix and the script runs

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @OferSadan for your suggestion to use `dir` command, it helped me to solve the problem. The "script.py" had an additional `.txt` extension added to it for some reason, but the Windows explorer only showed `.py` extension by default. Now I deleted the trailing `.txt` suffix and the script runs

Comment: In  settings, go to "update & security" -> "for developers". There are several suggested "file explorer" settings there for developers. This includes showing file extensions.